# Switch Between Bibliography and Appendix in fancyhdr

Tags: bibliographies, header-footer, conditionals, appendices, etoolbox

What I am trying to accomplish is a `fancyhdr` that places `Appendix` or `Bibliography` in the header with one single definition. So if I am in the bibliography it should display `Bibliography`, but should display `Appendix` otherwise.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\backmatter}{
    \fancyhdr[C]{\ifstrequal{\leftmark}{\MakeUppercase{\bibname}}
        {\bibname}{\appendixname\ \thechapter}}

\begin{document}
   \backmatter       
   \bibliography{my.bib}
   \appendix
   \chapter{Appendix}
\end{document}
```

The `ifstrequal` always evaluates as false and so always produces `Appendix` in the header. Thank you in advance for your help.

EDIT:
My new solution is as follows

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\preptocmd{\bibliography}{\fancyhead[C]{\bibname}}{}{}
\preptocmd{\appendix}{\fancyhead[C]{\appendixname\ \thechapter}}{}{}

\begin{document}       
   \bibliography{my.bib}
   \appendix
   \chapter{Appendix}
\end{document}
```

However, when my bibliography hits the third page it displays Appendix again.

Edit 2: The following works

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\preptocmd{\bibliography}{\cleardoublepage \fancyhead[C]{\bibname}}{}{}
\preptocmd{\appendix}{\cleardoublepage \fancyhead[C]{\appendixname\ \thechapter}}{}{}

\begin{document}       
   \bibliography{my.bib}
   \appendix
   \chapter{Appendix}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The page breaks may indeed give timing problems. I'd simply set the header explicitly in the document.

Comment: I am making a class file for other people to use on their thesis, so that is an option but sort of defeats the purpose. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: `\preptocmd` should be `\pretocmd` I think (2x)...

Answer (score 6):

The main problem is that `\leftmark` *doesn't* contain `\MakeUppercase{\bibname}`, but a more complicated thing. There are also other expansion problems.

If your backmatter is in that form, I suggest

```
\newif\ifbiblio
\newcommand{\backmatter}{%
  \fancyhead[C]{\ifbiblio \bibname\else\appendixname\ \thechapter\fi}%
  \bibliotrue
}
\appto\appendix{\clearpage\bibliofalse}
```

The conditional will be true from `\backmatter` until after the page change for the start of the appendices.

Comment: Yeah the problem is that appendix may come before the bibliography or after.

Comment: I could always just prepend and append to bibliography, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this.